# Good way to make Userdialog.Instance.Progress wait for method to execute C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, android-asynctask, mvvmcross

I'm trying to show a progress dialog showing the percent done with the method to wait everything + an `await Task.Delay(20);` And an await for the method I want to execute. Now I notice that with that task.delay the execution takes much longer.

What I want to achieve instead is that the progress.dialog calculates how long the method takes instead of putting a delay on it because this works a bit more slowly.

What are my options in this?

This is my code

```
    private async Task DownloadAllAlert()
    {
        //alert to download everything
        bool result = await DisplayAlert("Download", "Do you want to download everything?", "Yes", "No"); ;

        //alert is user chose yes
        if (result)
        {
            // loading dialog in percentage till downloading is done
            using (var progress = UserDialogs.Instance.Progress("Loading..."))
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    progress.PercentComplete = i;
                    await Api.DownloadAll();
                    await Task.Delay(20);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you're calling `Api.DownloadAll()` 100 times - are you sure that's what you want to do? also: `Now I notice that with that task.delay the execution takes much longer.`  - that's literally what `Task.Delay` does by design.

Comment: Oh my fault but if i set it to 1 the dialog ends before the method ends @FranzGleichmann

Answer (score 0):

try using Task in c#.

```
using (var progress = UserDialogs.Instance.Progress("Loading..."))
{
    await LoadData(ref progress);
}
```

call this function

```
public async Task LoadData(ref IProgressDialog progress);
{
  //await Task.Yield(); //add this line of code if on ios didnt work
  
 Task task1 = new Task(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50 ; i++) // loop untill 50% then increase sleeping thread time
        {
            progress.PercentComplete = i;     
            //sleeping for 1 second  
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        for (int i = 50; i < 100; i++) // loop untill 99% then stop
        {
            progress.PercentComplete = i;     
            //sleeping for 2 second  
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Task 1 complete");
    });

    Task task2 = new Task(() =>
    {
        await Api.DownloadAll();
        Console.WriteLine("Task 2 complete");
    });

    //starting the tasks  
    task1.Start();
    task2.Start();
    Task.WaitAny(task2);
    progress.PercentComplete = 100; // when task2 finish put it 100%
}
```

Comment: And where do i place my `using (var progress = UserDialogs.Instance.Progress("Loading..."))` then ? @Amjad S.

Comment: place my code inside using (var progress = UserDialogs.Instance.Progress("Loading..."))

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: no then the loading dialog does'nt pop up anymore

Comment: would you replace it with UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading?